# Enabling systemd's libcryptsetup

Tags: linux, yocto, systemd, openembedded, luks

I'm having the same issue then the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250300/yocto-openembedded-enabling-systemds-libcryptsetup/60005614#60005614). I ve created a file `cryptsetup_%.bbappend`.
I ve tried each of the following lines :

```
#PACKAGECONFIG[xz] = "--enable-xz,xz"
#PACKAGECONFIG[cryptsetup] = "--enable-libcryptsetup,cryptsetup"
#EXTRA_OECONF = "cryptsetup"
PACKAGECONFIG="xz cryptosetup"
```

and still I do not have any `cryptsetup service` or any `crypttab` file.

```
rootfs$ find . -type f -iname "*cryptsetup*"
./usr/lib/libcryptsetup.so.4.7.0
./usr/sbin/cryptsetup

rootfs$ ll etc/
total 192
drwxr-xr-x. 31 user user  4096 Jan 31 14:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 17 user user   177 Jan 31 14:04 ../
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user  5281 Jan 15 11:03 asound.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user    44 Jan 31 14:04 bluetooth/
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user  2529 Jan 15 11:21 busybox.links.nosuid
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user    91 Jan 15 11:21 busybox.links.suid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user    94 Jan 31 14:05 core-lsb/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user user    61 Jan 31 14:05 dbus-1/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user user   104 Jan 31 14:05 default/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user     6 Jan 15 11:05 depmod.d/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user user    34 Jan 31 14:03 dnf/
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user  3963 Jan 15 11:04 eGTouchL.ini
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user    38 Jan 29 15:46 filesystems
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user   125 Jan 31 14:05 firmware/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user user    38 Jan 15 10:38 fonts/
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user   637 Jan 29 15:46 fstab
...
```

I'm using the following conf:

```
BB_VERSION           = "1.38.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-eol-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "xxx"
DISTRO               = "xxx"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.14-sumo"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp neon callconvention-hard cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
```

Does anyone have any ideas or encountered a similar issue? Thanks!

Regards

Comment: is systemd in your DISTRO_FEATURES?

Comment: yes systemd is in DISTRO_FEATURE and define as default init manager also VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"

Comment: if you do 'bitbake cryptsetup -e > log', do you see the expected PACKAGECONFIG in the log file?